# Jquery animate() once then stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

Im trying to make a box animate when i scroll down to its position, but the animation wont stop, the element just keeps repeating the animation forever.
The code im using :

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function (e) {
    var value = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    if (value = 600) {

        jQuery( "body" ).addClass( "scroll" );
        jQuery('#car1').animate({top: '+=50px'}, 2000);
     }




    });
```

Comment: `value = 600` is assignment not comparison, use `===` or `==`.

Answer (score 0):

A single `=` isnt a comparison operator. It is in fact assigning a value to your variable.

That being said, your condition :

```
 if (value = 600)
```

is always true since `600` is a truthy value.

Try using `==` or `===`.

To anime once, you can use the class you are inputing on the body. Just invert your 2 lines and do a condition :

```
if(!jQuery("body").hasClass("scroll")) //Animate only if it haven't the class scroll
     jQuery('#car1').animate({top: '+=50px'}, 2000);
jQuery( "body" ).addClass( "scroll" );
```

Comment: i found out that scrollTop() wont accept any parameters, so basically the animation starts whenever i scroll down the page. thats the first problem. the second one is that i cant seem to stop the animation after it plays once.

Comment: Oh, i though you were doing `top : 50px` and didnt see the need to check for animation. Working on it.

Comment: I got the animation to play only once simply by changing the +=50 to +50
Now the only thing i need is to detect the height of the scrolling so the element will only animate when it becomes visible.

Comment: nope. but i changed the value to 3 and somehow it seems to work now.
any clue about the metrics used for scrolling values?

Comment: @user3320455 , im kinda stupid since I did not spotted that sooner, but using `==` will almost never work since the chance the srollTop value to be 600 is small. try `value >= 600;`.